# What does $f \circ g = g\circ f$ imply about $f$ and $g$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

For $f: R^n\rightarrow R^{n}$ and $g: R^n\rightarrow R^{n}$,

If $f \circ g = g\circ f$, what can be said about $f$ and $g$?

Are there any limitations on what $g$ can be given any certain $f$?

No real "answer",  but if anyone has any examples or knowledge, would be appreciated.

Comment: For linear maps $f,g$ a lot is known, see "commuting matrices". In general, say, for $f=id$ everything is possible for $g$. So your question is a little bit too broad. Do you have a more specific question about it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, yes I hadn't thought of the matrix interpretation of this, although the example with the identity matrix is just analogous to letting f(x)=x and then f(g(x))=g(f(x)), or is it somehow different?

Comment: What is the context of this question?  Are you studying general functions in the context of naive set theory, or particular functions in a more specific domain?

Comment: You are right, $f=id$ was for the general case. Then you can't give any restriction on $g$.

Comment: @AndrewL, no context, just was curious about what sort of weird stuff arrises when this limitation is imposed

Comment: Oliver, then it is more useful to restrict your question to a certain class of functions to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde i read that all diagonal matrices are commutable. Do diagonal matrices just represent a scaling of a different factor in each axis (base)?

Comment: @Oliver Murfett For diagonal matrices it's said within the context that $M$ always has $M^{-1}$. Thanks for clarifying this. I already felt I was stupid  (for *them* it means you can multiply by the opposite matrix from both of the sides, while multiplying in equation. Best of good luck anyways!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One elementary observation is that $f$ and $g$ must respect each other’s invariance.

Let $f$ and $g$ be maps $X → X$ on a set $X$. Furthermore, let $T, S ⊆ X$. If $g∘f = f∘g$, then
$$f(T) ⊆ S \implies f(g(T)) ⊆ g(S) \quad\text{and}\quad g(S) ⊆ T \implies g(f(S)) ⊆ f(T).$$

This in turn implies (for $T = S$) that $g$ and $f$ each induce well-defined maps on the $f$- and $g$-invariant subsets of $X$ respectively. In particular, $g$ maps fixed points of $f$ to fixed points of $f$ (and vice versa); furthermore, the orbit $\{g^n(T); n ∈ ℕ\}$ of $f$-invariant subsets $T$ consists only of $f$-invariant subsets and if $x$ is a fixed point of $f$, then so are $g(x), g^2(x), … $.